# If I set up a class method with 2 parameters defined from the other class, how can I get the values defined on the other class?

Tags: java

say I declared a `Camera` class

```
public class Camera {
}
```

then I created another class

```
public int compare (Camera camOne, Camera camTwo) {
}
```

If I set the value of `camOne.price`, where price is a defined value in the `Camera` class, how can I retrieve the value?

Comment: Yes, if ``price`` is ``public``.

Comment: if it's public, or you use some getter.

Comment: so should I define (public double price) , instead of double price? or does it not matter?

Comment: It depends where are you trying to access the price. Where is the other class? In the same package or different?

Comment: It's in the same package

Comment: If its in the same package then public would work as well as if you leave the variable without any access specifier (package private scope)

Comment: if I write these

     'if (camOneValue == camTwoValue && camOne.userRating == camTwo.userRating 
              && Math.abs(camOne.price - camTwo.price) < epsilon)'

could I compare the value between the cameras?
I defined int camOneValue to run another custom method, the price is defined in the Camera class already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most usually you would do one of two options:

**1. Least preferred:**

```
public class Camera {
    public float price;
}

public class CameraComparer {
    public float compare (Camera camOne, Camera camTwo) {
        // do something; e.g. return difference
        return camOne.price - camTwo.price;
    }
}
```

**2. More preferred/Standard:**

```
public class Camera {
    private float price;

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    } 
}

public class CameraComparer {
    public float compare (Camera camOne, Camera camTwo) {
        return camOne.getPrice() - camTwo.getPrice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it public:

```
public int var
```

Or create getter and setter methods:

```
public static int getVar ()
{
    return var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

Is there a reason why you would prefer not to use a private access modifier, and a getter method. I would be concerned to make it public just because of ease of use, as it could cause issues down the road.

Based on the comments I have read it seems like you are trying to make a compare method, which is fairly common. Maybe another approach could be implementing the [`Comparable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), and this would force you to implement the compareTo method.

See the following code for an example:

```
package com.grade;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Grade implements Comparable {

    private double percentage;

    public double getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(double percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o1) {
        if (o1 instanceof Grade) {
            Grade grade1 = (Grade) o1;
            if (this.getPercentage() > grade1.getPercentage()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (this.getPercentage() < grade1.getPercentage()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj1) {
        if (obj1 instanceof Grade) {
            Grade grade1 = (Grade) obj1;
            if (this.getPercentage() == grade1.getPercentage()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Grade chem = new Grade();
        chem.setPercentage(92.50);
        Grade astro = new Grade();
        astro.setPercentage(40.12);

        System.out.println(chem.compareTo(astro));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, what I need to do is to create a custom compare method, then retrieve the value from it in another method.

Comment: Ahh..gotcha. I am still hoping you decided to go with the private access modifer, along with a getter to access the value needed.